# Help me to create an action to reg a DLL

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

HI all,

In setup, I add a DLL MetaLib.DLL in Application Folder. Please help me how to create an action which will call command "regsvr32.exe MetaLib.DLL" when installing (after copying application file to folder). When removing, command "regsvr32.exe /u MetaLib.DLL" will be called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported by Visual Studio directly. However, you can try this:

- create your own EXE or DLL custom action which finds regsvr32.exe and your DLL and runs the registration command
- add it as custom action in your setup project
- use the same approach for uninstall

For example, you can create a custom EXE which receives the installer state (install or uninstall) through its command line.

Another solution is to use a free or commercial setup authoring tool which supports more custom action types.